# Hide category on listing page with ID Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to hide from a listing page from the WP Rentals theme an specific category that is created. I tried using a php function but is not working, my theory is that the category is registered by the theme as taxonomy property like is shown in the IMG 1 when putting the cursor on "edit".

The page ID = 657

The category ID = 78

Looking in the template-listing i find this:
$taxonomy_cat               =   'property_category';

[IMG1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkGsT.jpg)

```
// Exclude Category Posts from ID PAGE
function themeprefix_exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_page($page='657') ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-78' );//add your category number
    }
    return $query;
}
```